# Can I use a future tense to express the future general truth?

Tags: present-tense, present-simple

Can I use a future tense to express the future general truth like a present simple tense?

For example;

Water boils at 100 degrees now, but in the future, water will boil at 110 degrees for some reason (the future general truth).

I’ve fixed some typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes.**

Examples:

- Channel 4 (UK), [In the Future](https://www.channel4.com/programmes/in-the-future/on-demand/60682-005) (the first two episode titles use the present tense, but the rest use the future tense)
- IPCC, [Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.ipcc.ch/site/assets/uploads/2020/05/WGI_AR5_FAQ_EN.pdf) (many examples of *general* changes in conditions: "the next decade will be warmer", "average temperature... will be higher", "there will be net increases in rainfall")
- TVTropes, [Our Graphics Will Suck in the Future](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OurGraphicsWillSuckInTheFuture)
- Gil Scott-Heron, [The Revolution Will Not Be Televised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Revolution_Will_Not_Be_Televised) (used for revolutions/social upheaval in general, even if the author was referring to a specific revolution)