# use other tenses when talking about general truth?

Tags: tense, present-tense

I know that we should use present simple when talking about general truth like
The Sun rises in the east. However, if I add a time frame for it, will it still be used for present simple?

For example:

1. In the past, The Sun rises in the east.
2. In the future, The Sun rises in the east.
3. She said the Sun rises in the east.

Comment: In the past, the Sun ***rose*** in the east. In the future, the Sun ***will rise*** in the east. Using present simple for these is ungrammatical. For "she said the Sun rises in the east," you have a choice of simple past or simple present.

Comment: @FumbleFingers After seeing your linked Q/A I was going to agree with the duplicate target *except* that this question also has a future example, which that one doesn't cover. There's also this: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/291719/can-i-use-a-future-tense-to-express-the-future-general-truth?rq=1 but it's *only* about the future. If only something could be a duplicate of more than one question!

Comment: @QuackE.Duck: I think that linked "future general truth" question is a bit silly. General truths are *timeless*, which means OP's examples #1 and #2 here aren't just syntactically invalid - they're semantically nonsensical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That could make an insightful *answer* to the question, then! Although, while the boiling-point temperature example in the other question may be silly, it seems like it might be possible to come up with a real situation where the future "general truth" differs from the present one. What about, "In the present, 8k screens are the highest resolution. In the future, 16k screens will be the highest resolution."?

Comment: @QuackE.Duck: Screen resolutions aren't "universal truths". If you're gonna use  present simple when talking about general truth, you can't meaningfully restrict your assertion to some specific time-frame (whether past *or* future).